# SeekBar OnLongClickListener

Tags: java, android

Задача в `drag and drop seekBar'а`, но `seekBar` не обрабатывает `LongClick`.
Как можно выйти из этой ситуации? 
И еще вопрос, как можно временно отключить перетаскивание ползунка, я думал поможет что-то типа `setOnClickListener(null)`, но нет.
upd
Вот мой класс

```
public class CustomSeekBar extends SeekBar implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
Context context;
public CustomSeekBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        View.OnLongClickListener longClick = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Log.d("log", "long pressed --> ");
                return true;
            }
        };
        this.setOnLongClickListener(longClick);
    }
...
}
```

в логах ничего.

Comment: приведите пожалуйста пример кода, как вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: класс `SeekBar`, как и все виджеты - наследник `View`, соответственно реализует интерфейс `OnLongClickListener`, то что у вас что то не работает - ошибка в вашей реализации, приведите код, как вы это делаете, чтобы вам могли помочь. Для блокировки реакции виджета используйте метод `setEnabled(false)` или `setClickable(false)`

Comment: У вас ошика как мимэнимум в том что вы обращаетесь к View, это базовый класс, и к вашему Не имеет никакого отношения. А во-вторых, на сколько мне известно обработчики скбытий назначаются не в контрукторе класса. Т е для вашего случая достаточно будет назначить нужных обработчик для вашего элемента.

Comment: Это только проба, из конструктора конечно это уберется.
Если не к view обращаться то к чему? Не могли бы ссылку или пример кода написать, весь день бьюсь ответа не нашел.

Comment: SeecBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findElementById(R.id.your_seekbar); seekbar.setOnLongClickListner(this); могут быть синтаксические ошибки, но суть такая. Почитайте о работе с элементами, этотлксше чем задавать такие аопросы

Comment: @Viktor при всем уважении, не поленитесь и проверьте ваш код. LongClick НЕ РАБОТАЕТ на SeekBar.
Задача для меня реализовать drag and drop для кастомных компонентов, это первый компонент который вызвал у меня такие трудности.
Если у вас получится этим кодом сделать longClick, который у меня уже часов 10 не получается, я съем свою шляпу. Я думаю этот человек тоже ее съест http://www.cnblogs.com/TerryBlog/archive/2010/08/31/1813481.html

Comment: Ок, ничего не обещаю, но попробую)

Answer (score 2):

Сам ни разу не делел собственные обработчики, и, честно говоря не стал сильно разбираться... Но для вашей проблемы предлагаю такой вот костылек =) onLongClick() срабатывает после 1сек после начала пользования seekBar, или событие отменяется. Если имеется в виду что ползунок в это время должен быть на одном месте, то просто в seekBar записывать еще параметр progress и смотреть его изменения.

```
  @Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    startTimer(seekBar);
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    stopTimer(seekBar);
}

public void onLongClick(View v) {

}

private void stopTimer(SeekBar seekBar) {
    Timer timer = (Timer) seekBar.getTag();
    timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();
}

private void startTimer(final SeekBar seekBar){
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            onLongClick(seekBar);
        }
    }, 1000);
    seekBar.setTag(timer);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо (поставить пока + не могу, мало репы, но как только так сразу) за потраченное время на меня.
Вчера нечто подобное сделал только с потоком и sleep (тоже костыль), но работает абсолютно не отличимо для пользователя.
Согласитесь, что longClick весьма не стандартный, как показалось изначально @pavlofff и вам.

Comment: Да, соглашусь, не все так просто) кстати, я бы всё-таки не стал использовать sleep(), т к это останавливает весь UI поток, на сколько мне известно, а таймер выполняется в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Не, sleep у меня в отдельном потоке  new Thread(runnable)...
Аналогично приведенной ссылке мною выше, от китайца.

Comment: Тогда ок, хотя в таймере все уже сделано)